# Prevent * to be expanded in the bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Linux bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function Print()
{
    echo $1
}

var="*"
Print $var
```

Execution results:

```
alex@alex-linux:~/tmp$ ./sample-script 
sample-script
```

`*` is expanded to the list of files, which is actually script itself. How can I prevent this and see actual variable value? In general case, `var` can be more complicated than `*`, for example: `home/alex/mydir/*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to escape your variables, too:

```
Print "$var"
```

And in your function:

```
echo "$1"
```

Answer (score 4):

set -o noglob

will stop bash from expanding *
and can be removed with 'set +o noglob'

Comment: No, `unset` isn't used for that. You would use `set +o noglob`