# Bash intercepting wildcard in script

Tags: linux, bash

I am using Bash script to read line by line from a text file, which has special characters in it (regular expression). When I use `echo "${SOME_VAR}"` it does not display the text **as is**.

I am familiar with [Prevent * to be expanded in the bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470638/prevent-to-be-expanded-in-the-bash-script).

How can I display and use the text as is?

**UPDATE**
The text (TSV) file holds tuples similar to (the last entry is a psql query)

```
bathroom    bathroom    select name from photos where name ~* '\mbathroom((s)?|(''s)?)\M';
```

I am reading the CSV as follows:

```
tail -n+2 text.file | while IFS=$'\t' read x y z
do
    echo "${z}"
done
```

which gives the output

```
select name from photos where name ~* 'mbathroom((s)?|(''s)?)M');
```

note that the '\' is missing

Comment: show us your input and some code please

Comment: An alternative to the `tail` process (and avoiding the pipe which may cause subshell issues) would be `{ read; read; while IFS=$'\t' read z y z; do ... ; done; } < text.file`. Note the two throwaway `read` commands prior to the loop; all 3 share the redirected input to the command group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `-r` flag with `read`:

```
tail -n+2 text.file | while IFS=$'\t' read -r x y z
do
    echo "${z}"
done
```

From the `read` man page:

> -r     Do not treat a backslash character in any special way. Consider each backslash to be part of the input line.