# Prevent globbing in a bash script

Tags: bash, file, parameters, glob

I am trying to write a script that will operate on selected files.

```
#!/bin/bash
#ytest
lastArgNo=$#
sPattern=${!lastArgNo}
echo "operating on $sPattern"
#do operation on $sPattern
for sFile in $sPattern do
    #do something with each file
done
```

If I start this script with
Parameters *.JPG I get

```
operating on IMG_1282.JPG
```

which is the last file found for pattern *.JPG and only this file is being processed. I need the actual file pattern that is given on the commandline. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quote the argument to the script or run `set -f` before running your script to disable pathname expansion entirely (but remember to turn it back on in your script in that case).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent \* to be expanded in the bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470638/prevent-to-be-expanded-in-the-bash-script)

Comment: It's not a duplicate cause i can not set -o noglob within the script. And escaping with quotes doesn't solve the matter.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the actual pattern: the shell has already expanded it before launching your script. You do get the actual files as arguments, so what you should be doing is iterating over all the arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "operating on $# files"
for file; do
    # do something with each "$file"
done
```

What you are doing is setting lastArgNo to the number of args, the using indirect variable expansion to set sPattern to the value of the last argument. If you did `arg=1; sPattern=${!arg}` you would set sPattern to the first argument.