# How do I protect `*` from getting evaluated in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm expecting the following bash script to produce a .gitignore file with just the line

```
*~
```

but it produces instead the evaluation of `*~` (the files in the present directory that match this pattern).

```
#!/bin/bash

GITIGNORE=()
GITIGNORE+=("*~")

for line in "${GITIGNORE[@]}"
do
    echo ${line} >> .initial-gitignore
done
```

How do I protect the `*` from getting evaluated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent \* to be expanded in the bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470638/prevent-to-be-expanded-in-the-bash-script)

Answer (score 2):

Quote it while doing `echo` otherwise it will be expanded by shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

GITIGNORE=('*~')

for line in "${GITIGNORE[@]}"
do
    echo "$line" 
done >> .initial-gitignore
```

Answer (score 1):

anubhava's solution is correct but in your case its better that you do that.

```
cat << EOF >> .initial-gitignore
*~
*.bk
*.backup
EOF
```

That is assuming you want git to ignore `*~`, `*.bk`, `*.backup` you can add or remove any lines between the two `EOF`

Comment: In general use `<<'EOF'` unless you specifically want variable and command expansion performed in the document.